# Amazon-SNS. Limit delivery to SMS protocol while publishing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We are using Amazon SNS to sent SMS to customers through API(PHP). The topic may have email subscriptions as well as SMS subscriptions. I.e While creating a subscription,protocol may be email/sms. But we want to sent only SMS while publishing the messages. Email subscriptions should not receive any message. How to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible.** All subscribers to the topic will be sent the message.

You can provide different versions of messages for different types of subscriptions (eg SMS vs email), but you cannot control which type of subscriber receives a message.

Some alternatives:

- Maintain separate topics for situations where you wish to send a notification only to a subset of subscribers
- Use [Amazon Pinpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/) to specifically target mobile users with notification campaigns

Comment: our use-case is like as below. User is the topic. User email or Phone-number(or both) will be the subscription.  So if a message is published, it may delivered as both email and SMS.  Need to find a way to restrict delivery to SMS only. Thanks John for the reply

Comment: You can uses Amazon SNS to publish a message to a specific phone number, as opposed to sending the message to a topic with many subscribers. You can use Amazon SES (Simple Email Service) to send emails. So, you could handle each mode separately as individual messages.

Comment: What is the sns sending limit per day ?